# choropleth in ggmap not plotting correctly

Tags: r, ggmap, choropleth

I think I just made the world's weirdest choropleth.

The code is simple:

```
df$cut <- cut_interval(df$Count, 5)

ggplot(df, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = df$cut), colour = alpha("white", 1/2), size = 0.2) + 
  geom_polygon(data = df , colour = "white", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuRd")
```

(see [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/30SHHqGu) for a `dput` of the dataframe)

But the map is crazy:

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Looking at other [code](https://gist.github.com/hadley/233134) snippets, I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: I had a quick glance of your data. If I am not mistaken, your data does not have data for polygons. For instance, AL has several rows, and they all have identical lat and lon. If you want to draw a States map, you need to you another data set, which you can find in the `maps` package or `coroplethr` package. Another thing is that you have multiple years for some states. I wonder if you need to aggregate the data before you create a map. Otherwise, you would need to choose specific years you need, perhaps?

Comment: "If you want to draw a States map, you need to you another data set, which you can find in the maps package or coroplethr package." Do you know the name of this dataset? And YES you are right, I need to only select the data for one year. I guess I don't understand how a coropleth is actually constructed.

Comment: I specify the R package in the comment. Please have a look of CRAN maul or any other source. For subsetting data, you can find information on SO and many other places. :)

Comment: ah...reading this manual sorted me out. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/b-state-choropleth.html

Answer (score 1):

You could plot a choropleth like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(XML)
tab <- readHTMLTable("http://www.50states.com/abbreviations.htm", which=1)
df$region <- tolower(tab[match(df$State, tab[, 2]), 1])
states <- map_data("state")
choro <- merge(states, df, sort = FALSE, by = "region")
choro <- choro[order(choro$order), ]
ggplot(choro, aes(long, lat.x)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = Count), colour="grey55") +
  coord_quickmap() + 
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

First, you gotta match the region names in your `df$State` to the ones in `states$region`. Then, the map data is merged with your data frame and put in order. Finally, the plot is a piece of cake using ggplot.

[image]